# Sitecore overlapping error when deleting an item

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to delete an item, but I am getting an error:

```
The trees Content-CompanySites-MySite1-Data and Content-CompanySites-MySite1-Data-Configuration both contained the global path /sitecore/content/CompanySites/MySite1/Data/Configuration/Features/Project/ProjectOverviewPage - overlapping trees are not allowed.
```

Same thing happens when I tried to install package or add new item

Comment: Where do you see this error? are you using Unicorn?

Comment: This pops up when I try to delete an item. And also this similar error appears when I navigate to /unicorn.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review your Unicorn config files.
it is not allowed to have overlapping trees, however you can use Children exclusion patterns to have a root item config, and multiple child configurations.

In other words, the same item would be in several unicorn serialization folders, which of course is also asking for problems. Below some suggestions to fix this.

Search for Content-CompanySites-MySite1-Data and add

`<exclude children="true" />`

Example

```
<include name="Content-CompanySites-MySite1-Data" database="master"
path="/Content/CompanySites/MySite1/Data">
    <exclude children="true"/> <!-- include /nochildren, exclude all of /nochildren's children -->
</include>
```

Or remove the /sitecore/content/CompanySites/MySite1/Data/Configuration/Features/Project/ProjectOverviewPage config, or make a exception for this feature.

Example

```
<include name="Content-CompanySites-MySite1-Data" database="master"
path="/Content/CompanySites/MySite1/Data">
    <exclude path="/sitecore/content/CompanySites/MySite1/Data/Configuration/Features/" />
</include>
```

See also [TestConfiguration.xml](https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn.Tests/Predicates/TestConfiguration.xml) to get an idea of the possibilities to solve your specific issue.
See /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx to get insight of your merged config and where the patches came from.